# CMakeLists.txt doesn't create a usable makefile (Ubuntu and C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake

I'm quite new to C++ development and the idea of makefiles in general, so please bear with me. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, if that's relevant.

I'm trying to compile average-color.cpp, which uses the OpenCV library.

Project Folder:

```
bin  CMakeLists.txt  img  lib  obj  src

./bin:

./img:
test.png

./lib:
core.hpp  highgui.hpp  imgproc.hpp  opencv.hpp

./obj:
average-color.d  calculate-average-color.d  makefile-test.d
average-color.o  calculate-average-color.o  makefile-test.o

./src:
average-color.cpp
```

I'm able to compile a working file by using:

```
g++ average-color.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

while in the src directory, which leads me to believe that it's not a code error, it's a compiling error when using Cmake or some of the Makefiles I've found.

Below is my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
PROJECT (name)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
set( NAME_SRC
src/average-color.cpp    
)

set( NAME_HEADERS       
     lib/core.hpp
     lib/highgui.hpp
     lib/imgproc.hpp
     lib/opencv.hpp
)

    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
    link_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    add_executable( name ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )
```

When I run "cmake .", a makefile is generated. From there, running "make" fails: with the following output (couldn't format it nicely here). http://textuploader.com/d5wks

If anyone spots anything glaringly wrong with my CMakeLists.txt, please, explain, I haven't found very many clear explanations of all of this.

Comment: You are missing a `target_link_libraries()` in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: What should that link to? My lib folder?

Comment: ***My lib folder?*** Not the folder but the individual libraries. @SteveThibault answered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following after add_executable:

```
target_link_libraries(name ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

This will tell cmake to link the specific library your code references to the executable. Specifying the link directory just tells the linker where to find those libraries, target_link_libraries tells which libraries to link within the link directories.